# What should I learn to make my Swing login form check the database

Tags: java, database, swing, user-interface

I picked up Java programming as a hobby. Right now I am past the basics and currently learn Swing. I created a simple login form and want to connect it to a database. The problem is I know nothing about databases and where to start learning about them. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: JDBC is probably where you want to get started. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats good to hear that u piked up java as your hobby and also completed chapter of basic.I wish you best of luck.
Now,your query if u want to connect your program with database then there is API in java named as JDBC.
You can use jdbc or can use frameworks like hibernate and all.
If you want to learn database then start learning it because its necessary for almost all application.

Best of luck